# Variável fora dos limites da matriz

Tags: .net, array, string, vb.net

Estou tentando colocar os itens em posições de uma matriz, mas fico recebendo o erro de que a variável está fora dos limites da matriz. Não sei como arrumar o erro e preciso de ajuda.

Segue o código:

```
Dim posicao As String = String.Join("", itens)
Dim separa As String()
Dim contagem As String

contagem = ListBox1.Items.Count

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To contagem
separa = Split(posicao, ";")
cpf = separa(0)
nome = separa(1) 'O erro ocorre aqui.
anonasc = separa(2)
Next

TextBox1.Items.Add(cpf & ";" & nome & ";" & anonasc)
```

O programa não me aponta erros de código. Estou analisando a variável itens, que recebe as linhas de um arquivo .txt.

A variável local_arquivo recebe o .FileName de uma OpenFileDialog.

Variável `itens`:

```
Dim local_arquivo As String
itens = (My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(local_arquivo, System.Text.Encoding.Default)).Replace(vbLf, String.Empty).Split((CChar(vbCr)))
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(itens)
```

Comment: Seria bom colocar qual é o erro e onde ocorre, qual é o dado que está sendo analisado (`itens` e `ListBox1.Items`), etc.

Comment: Pronto, adicionei.

Comment: Mas qual é o conteúdo de `itens`?

Comment: Corrigido acima.

Comment: Estou falando do conteúdo, não da sua definição. Eu vou tentar responder do jeito que dá.

Comment: O conteúdo vai depender do que tá no arquivo que o usuário selecionar.

Comment: Sim,e é isto que eu quero saber para ver porque ocorre o erro.

Comment: São três CPFs, seguidos de nomes e ano de nascimento. São só exemplos. São separados pelo caracter ;.

000.000.000-00;Maria da Silva;1995
111.111.111-11;José de Souza;2005
222.222.222-22;João Antônio;1945

Comment: Estão separados por um ENTER, que não apareceu ao postar o comentário.

Comment: Você notou que a sintaxe do `Split` está errada? Viu na minha resposta o código funcionando?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (se tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Claramente o dado que está sendo analisado não possui os ponto e vírgula esperados. Isto é um dado mal formado, algo que pode acontecer.

Salvo ser uma interpretação errada do que o código deveria fazer, o correto é verificar antes de acessar o dado. Tem que decidir o que fazer se o dado está mal formado, provavelmente indicar um erro. Ou seja, não pode simplesmente acessar o `separa(0)`, `separa(1)` e `separa(2)`, antes de fazer isto tem que ver se o tamanho do *array* é 3. Se não for, tem que interromper o algoritmo e informar que o arquivo é inválido.

Um outro detalhe a ser analisado é se este `For` está servindo para alguma coisa. Me parece que não. Talvez seja intenção fazer algo com ele, mas neste momento ele é inútil.

Com a edição o problema pode ser outro. Eu fiz um teste com os dados passados e tudo funciona. Tive que mudar algumas coisas, o código nem compilava.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/MvJzr0). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x0FVJW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Bounds.vb).

A resposta continua valendo porque mesmo que os dados não estejam com problema agora, um dia poderão estar.

Comment: Desculpe se acabei te irritando. Conheço muito de VB, mas é a primeira vez que me aventuro no que estou precisando fazer. Estou testando seu código aqui, mas não sei o que está acontecendo que não compila, ele diz que não consegue criar formulário porque o valor não pode ser nulo.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim posicao As String = String.Join(";", itens)
Dim separa As String() = posicao.split(;)
Dim contagem As Integer = separa.count

 cpf = separa(0)
 nome = separa(1) 
 anonasc = separa(2)

for x as integer = 0 to Contagem-1
    textbox1.text = textbox1.text & ";" & separa(x)
next
```